# XML RSS Feed can't open

Tags: xml, rss

I was checking this XML feed (http://www.cma.gov.cn/2011xwzx/2011xqxxw/2011xqxyw/default_597.xml), but it can't open by using RSS reader. Please help!

I was checking XML validation and found no error. I see there are contents by using Notepad++, but can't pull the contents out.

Thanks much,